# Python mechanize set_proxies and internet options proxy settings

Tags: python, proxy, mechanize

I am unsure what is the problem. I have a script using mechanize to open a webpage. I want to setup proxy for it to do so.

I can do

```
br.set_proxies({'http':'proxyip:port'})
```

when I try to open a webpage it will timeout.

However if I dont use the proxy option above but set the same proxy in the internet options in windows, in connection, use proxy, the script will work and open the webpage thru the proxy.

What gives?
How exactly mechanize proxy support work? Is it based on the internet options proxy setting?
If so, why the set_proxies option in mechanize?
Is it possible to have a separate proxy for mechanize and that to be different from the internet options one (if there is one) or to work even if there is no proxy set up in IOpt.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your mentioned step you have to authenticate with your credentials, if this is required, for using the http-proxy. Otherwise mechanize knows to use a proxy, but not how to authenticate.
For more details see : [mechanizeDoc](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
# Explicitly configure proxies (Browser will attempt to set good defaults).
# Note the userinfo ("joe:password@") and port number (":3128") are optional.
br.set_proxies({"http": "joe:password@myproxy.example.com:3128",
"ftp": "proxy.example.com",
                })
# Add HTTP Basic/Digest auth username and password for HTTP proxy access.
# (equivalent to using "joe:password@..." form above)
# not necessary if credentials are not required
br.add_proxy_password("joe", "password")
```

You also have to check if your firewall is configured to pass the traffic heading for the proxy. Under Windows you might also experience that traffic can be send from your browser since this is configured in your firewall (as a source program).

Beside that you can use multiple proxies, since the mechanize proxy does not depend on other configurations.

Comment: Hi My proxy doesnt require authentication. I dont believe I need to use add_proxy_password in this case, do I?

Comment: No. In that case you do not need the add_proxy_password(). Please post the Traceback your code produced.

Comment: File "prodman.py", line 84, in login
  File "mechanize\_mechanize.pyc", line 203, in open
  File "mechanize\_mechanize.pyc", line 230, in _mech_open
  File "mechanize\_opener.pyc", line 193, in open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 344, in _open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 332, in _call_chain
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 1142, in http_open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 1118, in do_open
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>

Comment: I`d recommend to check your firewall and see if it is effected by the IE settings on using proxy. Maybe you have to configure your firewall to ensure your traffic will be passed which is send by mechanize. It sounds like its that way because of the working script, when IE is configured.

Comment: There is also this traceback. Similar to the above
   ae 230, in _mech_open
  File "mechanize\_opener.pyc", line 193, in open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 344, in _open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 332, in _call_chain
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 1142, in http_open
  File "mechanize\_urllib2_fork.pyc", line 1118, in do_open
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed becau
se the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or estab
lished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Comment: And again I would recommend to check the mentioned above. If you want this to be solved, you should be so kind to give further information. Please send at least the relevant source code and give some information about your setup regarding the proxy and your os. Its hard to fix it like that. Regarding your mechanize question everything is answered.

Comment: Hi
My firewall allows traffic from python. I even turned it off. I have given the relevant python code above.
My idea was that I can have a separate proxy in mechanize and have or not have any in internet options. But mechanize proxy to work correctly. It doesnt. If anyone have insight in that...